# Parse Server iOS SDK - Distinct query

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a builtin or standard way to apply a `query.distinct` query using the iOS SDK?

It is specifically listed in the JavaScript and Android API references. But not iOS.

I guess this means it is not implemented or supported? Yet - i.e. it may be an oversight right now? Or is there a reason it cannot be implemented on the platform?

And are there workarounds where I do not have to pull ALL the data down locally before processing / looping through the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Distinct` is not supported in the Parse iOS SDK (yet), because not every feature is implemented in all Parse client SKDs immediately, so it can take time until it trickles down into all SDKs.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel. I have a thread on the Parse community forum about the same subject. You are also contributing there. I will close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @jingo_man Yes please go ahead and close any duplicates. You find mostly the same people being active in either place and cross posting should be avoided.